# A musical commute to work

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I've always had... rules about how I get to work, and the eclectic music I listen to on the way.

Currently my playlist on my way to work is:

- Fergie
- Röyksopp
- 50 Cent
- Abba
- Harlem Spartans
- Houston Calls

My friend just introduced me to a track by an electro pop band called Petit Mal and it just made my commute so much faster!

Where do I live, and where do I work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You live and work

> in London, somewhere near **London Bridge** and the **Elephant and Castle** respectively.

The tracks are

> Fergie: **London Bridge**. Röyksopp: **Monument**. 50 Cent: Straight to the **Bank**. Abba: **Waterloo**. Harlem Spartans: **Kennington** Where it Started. Houston Calls: **Elephant and Castle**.

And of course you're now listening to

> Petit Mal's "Violence in the **Borough**".

In case it's not clear,

> these are all London underground stations, travelling one stop at a time.